# Getting certified bank statements in Malaysia from India for a Japanese visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, india, standard-visitor-visas, japan

I am a visitor in Malaysia applying for a visa for Japan.
How do I get certified bank statements in Malaysia for my bank account in India?

Comment: Are you resident in Malaysia, or just visiting?

Comment: I am Just Visiting

Comment: @GurmeetSingh You may not be able to apply for a visa as a tourist and will require to return to India

Answer (score 3):

The embassy of Japan in Malaysia [states](https://www.my.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/visainfo_d.html) :

> ### Criteria to apply visa in Malaysia
>
> Foreigners (non-Malaysian nationals) who wish to apply for Japan visa at the Embassy of Japan in Malaysia must meet the criteria below:
>
> 1. You are a permanent resident in Malaysia with My PR card or
> 2. You have a valid Malaysia long term visa (one year visa and above) in the passport, e.g. employment/ student/ dependent/ MM2H visa/ Residence pass.
>
> Please take note that Embassy of Japan in Malaysia do not accept visa applications from those who are under short social visit pass such as tourists, short-term business travelers and foreigners transiting in Malaysia.

You need to go back to India to apply for your visa